# What is the point of getting money?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart 8, the player can pick up coins. Having never played the game (only watched You-tubers play it), I don't see the importance of these. But, the people I watch seem to make a big deal about getting as many as they can, up to a max of 10.

**What is the point of collecting these coins?**

Answer (score 3):

3 uses.

- boosts a little bit of overall speed of your car, max out at 10 coins
- gives a very very tiny speed boost
- unlock unlockables (Every 50/100 coins will unlock a part)

Source: [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-8/Coins)